# ASP .NET Core Blazor Server Microsoft Identity remotely user logout

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I suppose a scenario where a user logged into the application, e.g. in a library, and forgot to log out. What should you do next to protect your own data and account from theft?
Application (Blazor Server) use Microsoft Identity from AzureB2C. This authentication method provide refresh token on 90 days, and auth token on 60min. Afrer 60min application getting new auth token. On Azure exist option "revoke" but I heard that feature not working with B2C.
Therefore, the user cannot log out remotely.
I thought about creating a list with sessionID. The user would select the session to logout, and then the logged in hacker in the application would be automatically logged out. But that's just one problem. I don't know how to create a unique session ID. For example, if a compromised computer were to be used a VPN, geolocation sessions would be pointless.

Maybe I don't understand Azure B2C identity. I need explanation.
Maybe anybody know how can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [invalidate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#invalidate-all-refresh-tokens-for-a-user) the refresh token in B2C.

You would still have to wait for the access token to expire.

Comment: Do you have any example? I was trying to look for in internet but, I can't implement that properly. I have B2C auth + net 6.0 on blazor server. Many tutorials is on v. 2.0/3.1 or Azure Ad. These aren't my cases at all.

Comment: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/revoke-sso-sessions